# Hiveql - Percentile with multiple where conditions in a select statement

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, percentile

I'm attempting to create a table which shows different percentile values based on X days prior to a set date.

The table I'm using looks like this;

| id | score | date | actual_score | survey_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 04-05-2021 | 4 | 05-05-2021 |
| A | 4 | 03-05-2021 | 5 | 05-05-2021 |

My current query is below;

```
SELECT
id,
PERCENTILE(score,0.25) AS p25_30_day_prior,                                                                             
PERCENTILE(score,0.50) AS p50_30_day_prior, 
PERCENTILE(score,0.75) AS p75_30_day_prior,
MAX(actual_score) AS actual_score
FROM Table A
WHERE date < survey_date and date >= date_sub(survey_date, 30)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

This works fine, however I would like to have multiple percentile values of 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75 for 1/7/14 as well as 30 days prior to survey date. Currently I use the where condition to obtain the correct date range. How would I have multiple percentiles in one table like the below?

| id | p25_30_day_prior | p25_14_day_prior | p25_7_day_prior | p25_1_day_prior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 | 3.5 | 5 |

I assume I'd need to use temp tables and join?

Answer (score 1):

Use case expressions and return NULL score if dates are not in required condition, percentile will ignore NULLs:

```
PERCENTILE(case when date < survey_date and date >= date_sub(survey_date, 30) then score else null end,0.25) AS p25_30_day_prior,
PERCENTILE(case when date < survey_date and date >= date_sub(survey_date, 14) then score else null end,0.25) AS p25_14_day_prior,
PERCENTILE(case when date < survey_date and date >= date_sub(survey_date, 7) then score else null end,0.25) AS p25_7_day_prior,
PERCENTILE(case when date < survey_date and date >= date_sub(survey_date, 1) then score else null end,0.25) AS p25_1_day_prior,
...
```

WHERE condition should allow all ranges, or use no WHERE at all.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - I'll give this a try.